# List all the running container in whole cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I want to know how I can check how many containers are currently running in my cluster? is there any command which shows me all the running containers in the cluster, not in a specific namespace. and how I can get the info about how many container per day get's run in my whole cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sum up all running containers in all pods. Try the following command.

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F/ '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all pods from all namespace :

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces
```

Then you can have the number of containers in the **READY** column.
You can find some more info in the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-all-containers-in-all-namespaces)

Answer (score 1):

You can get pods by nodes and phase:

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces=true --no-headers -o=custom-columns=NODE:.spec.nodeName,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase --sort-by='.metadata.name'
```

hope this helps